# How to keep top border after hiding toolbar in ExtJS htmleditor

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have an htmleditor field in a form I created in extjs 4.2.  I have it hiding the toolbar in the afterrender listener:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(editor) {
        editor.getToolbar().hide();
    },
    scope: this
}
```

However, it looks like hiding it also hides the top border of the text area.  Is there a way I can add the border back or have it only hide the toolbar and not the top border?

[image: Missing top border after hiding toolbar]

Comment: Please, provide more information about your view or make a fiddle on https://fiddle.sencha.com
Did you try `'border'` config for border styling?

Answer (score 0):

Add `cls: topBorder` and add this to your css file:

```
.topBorder {
border-top: 1px solid #b5b8c8;
}
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS class:

```
.x-component.x-html-editor-input.x-box-item.x-component-default {
    border-top: 1px solid #b5b8c8;
}
```